# Perforce - getting stream name in a trigger script

Tags: triggers, client, perforce, perforce-stream

I want to create a trigger for preventing check-out on files if they belong to a specific stream.

I am using the pre-user-edit trigger.

The trigger executes a Perl script.

When I execute in the Perl script a p4 command, then I get this error:

Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.

What I did is getting the stream name out of the client name (which is passed to the Perl script):

```
 $ stream = `p4 client -o $ client | grep ^Stream: | awk '{print \$ 2}'`;
 chomp $ stream;
```

This does not work.

Also, trying to assign $p4 with new P4, fails.

Anyone has a clue how to solve this?

At least, give me a way to extract the stream name out the client name?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your question how to resolve the "password invalid or unset" error? Or is your question how to figure out the stream name to which a particular client workspace is currently set?

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative,
$ stream = `p4 -F "%Stream%" -ztag client -o`;

This would just give you the stream name(no trimming is required)

Comment: wonderful, this works well

Answer (score 2):

You must be logged in to Perforce to run `p4 client`. In interactive shell you do this by `p4 login` which prompts you for a password. Once that's validated, Perforce keeps you logged in for a week or so (depends on your P4 server setting). During that week your command should succeed, but once your session expires it will start failing again.

If session expiry is a problem for you, you will need to get hold of a non-expiring ticket. That must be enabled by your server admin (read "To create tickets that do not expire..." att [p4 login](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_login.html)). See also [P4TICKETS](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/P4TICKETS.html).

Answer (score 1):

As an other alternative, use `p4 switch` to show the name of the current stream.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to get the current stream name! This should be the accepted answer.